# AWS Lambda returns respond as 502 Bad request for option method

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda, bad-request

I have a lambda (LAMBDA_PROXY) function with API gateway which is implemented in Golang (go-chi router).
when I invoke lambda from postman or browser, it gives 502 Bad Gateway status. In CloudWatch, I found following error message

> Error while generating proxy response: Status code not set on response: errorString null

Answer (score 0):

You need to respond with the correct response when using the "Use Lambda as Proxy" checkbox. Check out [this document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-integration-settings-integration-response.html).

[This](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-custom-integrations.html) may be more appropriate

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is because, when you're using the API Gateway + Lambda proxy integration, the ***return value*** from the lambda function must be in the following [JSON format](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/malformed-502-api-gateway/):

```
{
    "isBase64Encoded": true|false,
    "statusCode": httpStatusCode,
    "headers": { "headerName": "headerValue", ... },
    "body": "..."
}
```

Since you are using Golang, you can edit the ***return value*** of your main.go function by adding the following snippet as follows :

```
return events.APIGatewayProxyResponse{
    Body: string(body), 
    StatusCode: 200
}, nil
```

Hope this helps!